Quantum SVM Implementation Error on IBM Quantum Machine: ‘CircuitError: Name Conflict
I'm working on a project involving quantum support vector machines using the method from the Quantum Kernel Machine Learning Tutorial by the Qiskit community. While implementing the code on a real IBM quantum machine, I encountered CircuitError: "name conflict adding parameter 'x[1]'" error.
Has anyone faced this issue, or does anyone know how to resolve it? Any insights would be appreciated!
Code:
    from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, Sampler, Session
    from qiskit_machine_learning.datasets import ad_hoc_data
    from qiskit import transpile
    from qiskit.circuit.library import ZZFeatureMap
    from qiskit_algorithms.state_fidelities import ComputeUncompute
    from qiskit_machine_learning.kernels import FidelityQuantumKernel
    from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
    
    
    # Load Dataset
    adhoc_dimension = 2
    train_features, train_labels, test_features, test_labels, adhoc_total = ad_hoc_data(
        training_size=20,
        test_size=5,
        n=adhoc_dimension,
        gap=0.3,
        plot_data=False,
        one_hot=False,
        include_sample_total=True,
    )
    
    # initialize backend service
    service = QiskitRuntimeService()
    n_qubits=2
    backend = service.least_busy(operational=True, simulator=False, min_num_qubits=n_qubits)
    
    
    adhoc_feature_map = ZZFeatureMap(feature_dimension=adhoc_dimension, reps=2, entanglement="linear")
    
    #transpile circuit
    pass_manager = generate_preset_pass_manager(optimization_level=1, backend=backend)
    isa_circuit = pass_manager.run(adhoc_feature_map)
    
    # calculate kernel matrices
    with Session(service= service, backend=backend) as session:
        sampler = Sampler(backend)
        fidelity = ComputeUncompute(sampler=sampler)
        adhoc_kernel = FidelityQuantumKernel(fidelity=fidelity, feature_map=isa_circuit)
        adhoc_matrix_train = adhoc_kernel.evaluate(x_vec=train_features,y_vec=train_features)
        adhoc_matrix_test = adhoc_kernel.evaluate(x_vec=test_features, y_vec=train_features)

Got following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CircuitError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[51], line 7
      4 fidelity = ComputeUncompute(sampler=sampler)
      6 adhoc_kernel = FidelityQuantumKernel(fidelity=fidelity, feature_map=isa_circuit)
----> 7 adhoc_matrix_train = adhoc_kernel.evaluate(x_vec=train_features,y_vec=train_features)
      8 adhoc_matrix_test = adhoc_kernel.evaluate(x_vec=test_features, y_vec=train_features)

File ~/Desktop/IMB/machine/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qiskit_machine_learning/kernels/fidelity_quantum_kernel.py:114, in FidelityQuantumKernel.evaluate(self, x_vec, y_vec)
    112 if is_symmetric:
    113     left_parameters, right_parameters, indices = self._get_symmetric_parameterization(x_vec)
--> 114     kernel_matrix = self._get_symmetric_kernel_matrix(
    115         kernel_shape, left_parameters, right_parameters, indices
    116     )
    117 else:
    118     left_parameters, right_parameters, indices = self._get_parameterization(x_vec, y_vec)

File ~/Desktop/IMB/machine/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qiskit_machine_learning/kernels/fidelity_quantum_kernel.py:202, in FidelityQuantumKernel._get_symmetric_kernel_matrix(self, kernel_shape, left_parameters, right_parameters, indices)
    192 def _get_symmetric_kernel_matrix(
    193     self,
    194     kernel_shape: tuple[int, int],
   (...)
    197     indices: KernelIndices,
    198 ) -> np.ndarray:
    199     """
    200     Given a set of parameterization, this computes the kernel matrix.
    201     """
--> 202     kernel_entries = self._get_kernel_entries(left_parameters, right_parameters)
    203     kernel_matrix = np.ones(kernel_shape)
    205     for i, (col, row) in enumerate(indices):

File ~/Desktop/IMB/machine/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qiskit_machine_learning/kernels/fidelity_quantum_kernel.py:223, in FidelityQuantumKernel._get_kernel_entries(self, left_parameters, right_parameters)
    221 if num_circuits != 0:
    222     if self.max_circuits_per_job is None:
--> 223         job = self._fidelity.run(
    224             [self._feature_map] * num_circuits,
    225             [self._feature_map] * num_circuits,
    226             left_parameters,
    227             right_parameters,
    228         )
    229         kernel_entries = job.result().fidelities
    230     else:
    231         # Determine the number of chunks needed

File ~/Desktop/IMB/machine/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qiskit_algorithms/state_fidelities/base_state_fidelity.py:298, in BaseStateFidelity.run(self, circuits_1, circuits_2, values_1, values_2, **options)
    270 def run(
    271     self,
    272     circuits_1: QuantumCircuit | Sequence[QuantumCircuit],
   (...)
    276     **options,
    277 ) -> AlgorithmJob:
    278     r"""
    279     Runs asynchronously the state overlap (fidelity) calculation between two
    280     (parametrized) circuits (first and second) for a specific set of parameter
   (...)
    296         The job's result is an instance of :class:`.StateFidelityResult`.
    297     """
--> 298     job = self._run(circuits_1, circuits_2, values_1, values_2, **options)
    300     job.submit()
    301     return job

File ~/Desktop/IMB/machine/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qiskit_algorithms/state_fidelities/compute_uncompute.py:147, in ComputeUncompute._run(self, circuits_1, circuits_2, values_1, values_2, **options)
    116 def _run(
    117     self,
    118     circuits_1: QuantumCircuit | Sequence[QuantumCircuit],
   (...)
    122     **options,
    123 ) -> AlgorithmJob:
    124     r"""
    125     Computes the state overlap (fidelity) calculation between two
    126     (parametrized) circuits (first and second) for a specific set of parameter
   (...)
    144         AlgorithmError: If the sampler job is not completed successfully.
    145     """
--> 147     circuits = self._construct_circuits(circuits_1, circuits_2)
    148     if len(circuits) == 0:
    149         raise ValueError(
    150             "At least one pair of circuits must be defined to calculate the state overlap."
    151         )

File ~/Desktop/IMB/machine/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qiskit_algorithms/state_fidelities/base_state_fidelity.py:187, in BaseStateFidelity._construct_circuits(self, circuits_1, circuits_2)
    184 # re-parametrize input circuits
    185 # TODO: make smarter checks to avoid unnecessary re-parametrizations
    186 parameters_1 = ParameterVector("x", circuit_1.num_parameters)
--> 187 parametrized_circuit_1 = circuit_1.assign_parameters(parameters_1)
    188 parameters_2 = ParameterVector("y", circuit_2.num_parameters)
    189 parametrized_circuit_2 = circuit_2.assign_parameters(parameters_2)

File ~/Desktop/IMB/machine/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qiskit/circuit/quantumcircuit.py:4345, in QuantumCircuit.assign_parameters(self, parameters, inplace, flat_input, strict)
   4343 else:
   4344     parameter_binds = _ParameterBindsSequence(target._data.parameters, parameters)
-> 4345     target._data.assign_parameters_iterable(parameters)
   4347 # Finally, assign the parameters inside any of the calibrations.  We don't track these in
   4348 # the `ParameterTable`, so we manually reconstruct things.
   4349 def map_calibration(qubits, parameters, schedule):

CircuitError: "name conflict adding parameter 'x[1]'"
```

